# getting value from dynamically created textbox and checkbox

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

i write the following code to create code

```
Dim i, x, y As Integer
    x = 30
    y = 25
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chk As New CheckBox()
        chk.Text = dt1.Rows(i)(0)
        chk.Location = New Point(x, y)
        chk.Font = fnt
        chk.Width = 450
        chk.ForeColor = Color.White

        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(chk)
        chk.Name = "chk" & Convert.ToString(i)
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.Location = New Point(x, y + 23)
        txt.Font = fnt
        txt.Multiline = True
        txt.Height = 46
        txt.Width = 400
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(txt)
        txt.Name = "txt" & Convert.ToString(i)
        y = y + 69
```

i want to retrive the textvalue of checkbox whose checked property is true and respective  textbox at a buttonclick event. Problem is in finding the controls and their textvalue. 
any one can help?Thanks in Advance.dt1 is datatable .For window form application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new VB Windows Form application and add a button then replace the code of the form with this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.Name = "myText"
        txt.Left = Me.Width / 2
        txt.Top = Me.Height / 2
        txt.Text = "here is my text"

        Me.Controls.Add(txt)              'This will add the dynamically created object

        Dim anotherObj As TextBox = Me.Controls.Item("myText")    'because we know the name of the object we created before, we can retreive it back

        MsgBox(anotherObj.Text)      'and we can also get the text we assigned earlier.


    End Sub


End Class
```

The last 2 lines can be put inside another Sub() and you would still have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Where is that code in the life cycle? It should be before Page_Load in order to get the controls values later. You can give it an Id like

```
 chk.ID = myId;
```

To get the value you can write something like this

```
 CheckBox cb  =(CheckBox)Page.FindControl(myId);
```

Comment: this is for window form application, where we assign name to controls and it is assign in my code  chk.Name = "chk" & Convert.ToString(i)

Comment: hum right, so Page won't work. sorry, thought it was webforms.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping through the controls? Something like below:

```
    Dim ctrlName As String = String.Empty
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(ctrl, CheckBox)

            If chk.Checked Then
                ctrlName = chk.Name.Replace("chk", "txt")
            End If
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox AndAlso ctrl.Name = ctrlName Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            Dim val As String = txt.Text
            ctrlName = String.Empty
        End If
    Next
```

I haven't tested this, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you must [re-create all dynamic controls on postback](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

Your `Page` is just a class remember and it is instantiated once per request, if it doesn't recreate these controls as well as the associated handlers on the postback request then you won't get anything happen..

You need to recreate these controls prior to `Page_Load`, you can do this in `Page_Init` or override the `CreateChildControls` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim txtbranchname1 As TextBox
    Private boxes(1) As TextBox

    newbox = New TextBox
    newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    newbox.Name = "txtBranchName"
    newbox.TabIndex = 1
    newbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    AddHandler newbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
    AddHandler newbox.KeyDown, AddressOf TextBox_Keydown
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newbox)
    txtbranchname1 = Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Item("txtBranchName")

    'Enter the value to textbox on runtime
    MsgBox( txtbranchname1.Text)

    'assign value to textbox
    txtbranchname1.Text = "Something"
```